# Flowplayer Not Looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, flowplayer

I am having trouble with flowplayer looping.  I have tried a bunch of different stuff, but I can't get it to loop.  It plays once and stops.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="home_fplayer" href="/File/1.mp4"><img alt="" src="/File/ld.jpg" /></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $f("home_fplayer", {src:"/js/flowplayer/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.7.swf", wmode: 'opaque'}, 
    {
        key: '#$1432062db092e251814',
        plugins: 
        {
            controls: null
        },
        loop: true,
        clip: 
        {
            autoPlay: true,
            onBeforePause: function(clip) 
            {
               return false;
            },
            onFinish: function () 
            {
                this.play(0);return false;
            },
            onBeforeFinish: function () 
            {
                this.play(0);return false;
            }
        }
    }).ipad();

    $f("home_fplayer").play();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set onBeforeFinish to return false:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $f("home_fplayer",{src:"/js/flowplayer/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.7.swf",wmode:'opaque'},
        {
        key: '#$1432062db092e251814',
        plugins:{
            controls: null
        },
        clip:{
            autoPlay: true
        },
        onBeforeFinish:function(){
            return false;
        }
    }).ipad();

    $f("home_fplayer").play();
});
```

Comment: i am returning false onBeforeFinish.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use the [playlist plugin](http://flowplayer.org/plugins/javascript/playlist.html) to enable looping.